# Graph of function, continuous projection

Tags: gn.general-topology

$X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a map (we don't suppose that $f$ is continuous). Consider 
$A=\{(x,f(x))\in X\times Y| x\in X\}$. is  $\pi: A\rightarrow X$, $$(x,f(x))\mapsto x$$ a homeomorphism ? If not, is it enough to assume that $A$ is closed subspace in $ X\times Y$ ? 
 If $X$ and $Y$ are metrizable spaces, how to prove that $\pi$ is a homemorphism using sequential continuity ? Suppose that by miracle $\pi$ is homeomorphism but $f$ is not continuous, is it possible such phenomenon ?

Comment: The graph might be disconnected but the domain not.

Comment: The inverse map of $\pi $ is $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$. If it is continuous, its composition with the second projection $-$ that is, $f\ -$  is continuous.

Comment: As to the second question, note that $A:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:xy=1\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is the graph of a discontinuous function, it is certainly not homeomorphic to  $\mathbb{R}$ (it's disconnected).

Answer (score 3):

The projection $\pi : A \to X$ is a homeomorphism iff $f$ is continuous. For one direction, let $\pi_Y : X \times Y \to Y$ be projection onto the second coordinate, which is continuous, and notice that $f = \pi_Y \circ \pi^{-1}$.  Conversely, if $f$ is continuous then $\pi^{-1}(x) = (x, f(x))$ is continuous.

This does not necessarily happen when $A$ is closed.  Following the idea from JP McCarthy's comment, consider for instance $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ (which are metrizable),  $f(x) = 1/x$ for $x>0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$.  Then the graph $A$ is closed but is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (for instance, $A$ is not connected).

If $A$ is actually *compact* and $X$ is Hausdorff then you are in business, because a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is always a homeomorphism.

In the metric space context, a sequence-based proof could use the "double subsequence trick": suppose $x_n \to x$ in $X$.  We wish to show $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.  Suppose the contrary; then there is some neighborhood $U$ of $f(x)$ and a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $f(x_{n_k}) \notin U$ for all $k$.  Now by compactness the sequence $(x_{n_k}, f(x_{n_k}))$ in $A$ must have a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_{k_j}}, f(x_{n_{k_j}}))$.  Call the limit $(x', y')$, so that $x_{n_{k_j}} \to x'$ and $f(x_{n_{k_j}}) \to y'$.  Since $x_{n_{k_j}}$ is a subsequence of $x_n$, it converges to $x$, so $x=x'$ since limits in a metric space are unique.  And since $A$ is the graph of $f$, $(x,y') \in A$ implies $y' = f(x)$.  Therefore $f(x_{n_{k_j}}) \to f(x)$.  But this is absurd because by construction, none of the $f(x_{n_{k_j}})$ are in $U$.